# Save millions of files on windows

Tags: c#, filesystems, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

My system will save ~20-40 million image files 
Each file is 150-300KB
My application will run on windows server 2012 R2 and the files will be saved on storage (don't know which one yet)
My application is written in C#

My requirements are:
- The system will constantly delete old files and save new files (around 100K files per day)
- The most recent images will be automatically displayed to users on web and wpf applications
- I need fast access to recent files (last week) for report purposes

What is the best practice for storing / organizing this amount of files?

Comment: Your questions is not very clear. What are you trying to do? Generate random garbage files with 150-300kb each?

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes. Seriously, what answer do you expect? Be more specific - what are you going to do with these files after your application will save them?

Comment: Could you give some informationen about the requirements? Functional as well as  Non-Functional.

Answer (score 1):

Broad questions much? If you're asking about how to organize them for efficient access that's a bit harder to answer without knowing the reason you're storing that many files.

Let me explain:
Lets say you're storing a ton of log files. Odds are your users are going to be most interested in the logs from the last week or so. So storing your data on disk in a way that you can easily access the files by day (e.g. yyyy-mm-dd.log) will speed up getting access to a specific day log.

Now instead think of it like a phone book and you're accessing peoples names. Well storing it by the time you inserted that name in the phone book really isn't going to help you get to the result you want quickly. Better come up with a better sorting algorithm.

Essentially look at how your data will be accessed, try to sort it in a logical manner so that you can do a binary search algorithm or better algorithm on it.

I'd highly recommend rewording your question so it is clearer though.